# Can I wrap CKEditor's editing block in several tags to mimic context?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I need to wrap editing block's in some divs to mimic context, so the preview does render with according CSS stylesheet.

I'd like CKEditor to render HTML inside

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <div class="header">
   <!-- ckeditor edited HTML here -->
  </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

so the, for example, H1 will look like rendered on site.

Can I achieve this?

Comment: CKEditor (at least in ASP.NET which is where I use it) is implemented through an IFrame, and therefore does not pick up any styles from the parent container.  I do not know how you implement actual styles within CKEditor, but would be interested to see any answers you get

Comment: An idea is to put wrapper html that mimics context into ckeditor and then strip it after saving, however that seems to be a little dirty solution

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra styles to the editor in the config.js file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
   config.contentsCss = ['/Content/Style/site.css', '/Content/Style/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'];
}
```